# bash in-place replace dashes only on 1st column of a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file which contains 2 columns as follows:

```
some-app-name1     feature/branchname  
another-app-name1  feature-branch-name  
some-app-name2     hotfix-branch-name  
frontend-app-name  branchname  
another-app-name2  main-branch-name
```

Using awk or sed I want to replace dashes and make next letter uppercase but only in first column of this file so the end
ouput will look like this:

```
someAppName1     feature/branchname  
anotherAppName1  feature-branch-name  
someAppName2     hotfix-branch-name  
frontendAppName  branchname  
anotherAppName2  main-branch-name
```

Tried the following sed, but it replaces all the dashes in the file:
`sed -E -i 's/-(.)/\u\1/g'`

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you're using GNU sed, here is one way:

```
sed -E ':l; s/^(\S*)-(.)/\1\u\2/; tl'
```

Answer (score 2):

To *actually honor the title* and use no tools other than bash (whereas awk, perl, and sed are all things other than bash), one might write something like the following (which requires bash 4.x or greater):

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r col1 col2; do
  while [[ $col1 =~ -([[:lower:]]) ]]; do
    replacement=${BASH_REMATCH[1]^^}
    col1=${col1//${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/$replacement}
  done
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$col1" "$col2"
done
```

Explanation:

- `IFS=$'\t' read -r col1 col2` reads the first tab-separated column into `$col1`, and everything else into `$col2`.
- `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` matches `$string` against the ERE-syntax regular expression in `$regex`, and uses the result to populate the `BASH_REMATCH` array (putting the whole matched contents into `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}`, the first match group into `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, etc).
- `${var^^}` returns a version of the contents of `$var` with all characters shifted to uppercase.
- `${var//$match/$replace}` finds all instances of `$match` and substitutes `$replace`.

Thus, the above, for each line, splits it into columns on tab characters; looks for whether the first column has strings with a dash followed by a lowercase character, and replaces that two-character string matched by the regex with a single upper-case character; when no more replacements remain to be done, prints the line.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
some-app-name1     feature/branchname  
another-app-name1  feature-branch-name  
some-app-name2     hotfix-branch-name  
frontend-app-name  branchname  
another-app-name2  main-branch-name
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS=""}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){if($i~/[[:space:]]/){break};if($(i-1)=="-"){$i=toupper($i);$(i-1)=""}};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
someAppName1     feature/branchname  
anotherAppName1  feature-branch-name  
someAppName2     hotfix-branch-name  
frontendAppName  branchname  
anotherAppName2  main-branch-name
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that every character is field and empty string is output field separator, then starting at 2nd character I loop over characters, if character is whitespace I terminate (`break`) loop, if previous field is dash I uppercase current field and empty previous field. When loop is over I `print` such changed line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ perl -anE '$F[0] =~ s/-(\w)/uc($1)/ge; say join "\t", @F' file
someAppName1    feature/branchname
anotherAppName1 feature-branch-name
someAppName2    hotfix-branch-name
frontendAppName branchname
anotherAppName2 main-branch-name
```